# Can't start rails server after macbook upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I'm using macbook for programming, and I got an upgrade notice, but after upgrading my macbook to the newest version, I can't start the rails server anymore. I get these errors when I run rails s.
The version I'm using is macOS Catalina version 10.15.4

```
   Kaspers-MacBook-Air:BetterWing kaspervalentin$ rails s
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        61: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
        60: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        59: from /Users/kaspervalentin/BetterWing/BetterWing/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
        58: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        57: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        56: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        55: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        54: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        53: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        52: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        51: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        50: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        49: from /Users/kaspervalentin/BetterWing/BetterWing/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        48: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        47: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        46: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        45: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        44: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        43: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        42: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        41: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
        40: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        39: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
        38: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
        37: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        36: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        35: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        34: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
        33: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
        32: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
        31: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        30: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        29: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        28: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        27: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        26: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        25: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        24: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
        23: from /Users/kaspervalentin/BetterWing/BetterWing/config/application.rb:5:in `<main>'
        22: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
        21: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
        20: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
        19: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
        18: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
        17: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        16: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        15: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        14: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        13: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        12: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
        11: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/uglifier-4.2.0/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `<main>'
        10: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
         9: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
         8: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
         7: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
         6: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         5: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
         4: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         3: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
         2: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<main>'
         1: from /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    /Users/kaspervalentin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:58:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
```

Comment: Error says `Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)`. Have you tried reading through that?

Comment: Yes and I've installed the gem with this command 'gem install execjs' but I still get the errors. I'm not sure what else I need to do

Comment: Got it working by installing nodejs

Comment: Please add reply to your question so that others can benefit from it

Answer (score 1):

Got it working by installing nodejs

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue and could resolve it by installing nodejs version 12.18.0 for OS X from nodejs.org on my MacBook